# How do I open the current directory in a new tab?

Tags: terminal, osx, zsh, tabs

#### My environment

- Terminal.app 2.9.4 on macOS
- zsh 5.7.1

---

When I used bash, Terminal could open current directory in a new tab, but it have not been able to do that since I changed to zsh.

In the app setting, even though it is set as "Same Working Directory".

[image]

If I would write something on `.zshrc` or `.zprofile`, would it be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://blog.callstack.io/supercharge-your-terminal-with-zsh-8b369d689770

```
# Open new tabs in same directory
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ]]; then
  function chpwd {
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "file://$HOSTNAME${PWD// /%20}"
  }
  chpwd
fi
```

Note that the only percent-encoding it does on the path is to replace spaces with "%20". This should be replaced with a more robust encoding.

Comment: Thanks to the article you found, I've realized what I wanted to do! And I’d examine your viewpoint. Thank you very much!! ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Click the blue text:

[image: Terminal preferences window with popup showing how to notify Terminal of the current working directory]

So you just need to add that little escape sequence to your prompt so that Terminal knows where you are. Easy!

Or, if you think that's a little cryptic, let's take a look at how bash manages to pull it off. Checking `man bash` reveals that when bash is invoked as an interactive login shell (this should be the default when opening a Terminal window or tab), one of the files it references is `/etc/profile`.

A quick peek at `/etc/profile` shows that it may load `/etc/bashrc`.

And looking inside `/etc/bashrc` shows that it tries to load `/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM`. Quick check:

```
> echo $TERM_PROGRAM
Apple_Terminal
```

A `less /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` later, and jackpot! Right up near the top:

```bash
# Tell the terminal about the current working directory at each prompt.
```

Followed by a function that does just that, ripe for inclusion in a (bash) prompt. I'm going to refrain from copying the function here, as I'm not entirely sure of the legality of doing so, though I will include the last line of the function, as I believe that's trivial enough to be fair use:

```bash
printf '\e]7;%s\a' "file://$HOSTNAME$url_path"
```

This is basically that cryptic escape sequence from the preferences window popup. The rest of the function is entirely about setting up the `$url_path` variable with the necessary percent_encoding. You'll need to translate that stuff to zsh or just extract it to an external bash script and call that, though firing up a bash instance every time might slow your prompt down a bit.

Comment: Thanks to you, I’ve roughly learned how that was being realised! They seem to be very well configured. I’ll try to translate it in reference to them

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following keyboard shortcut:

`cmd + ctrl + o`

Comment: I tried that way, but there is no response. I also tried `Ctrl + Cmd + N` and `Opt + Cmd + N or O` etc., but the results are the same.